# in an `async` function are the input parameters preserved over an `await`

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have some browser code which has been showing some mysterious errors when running over a slow link. I am coming to the conclusion that the `event.detail` parameter is getting corrupted.

So I have an async function (as a method on a class) a bit like the following:

```
async doUpdate(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  const response = await readSomethingFromRemoteDatabase(this.id, e.detail.anotherid);
  const myentity = this.entities.find(x => x.id === e.detail.anotherid)
  if (typeof myentity !== 'undefined') {
    //do something to update local data
  }
}
```

I expect `myentity` to be found, but occasionally it isn't.

I have since changed the code to become the following:

```
async doUpdate(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  const data = e.detail
  const response = await readSomethingFromRemoteDatabase(this.id, e.detail.anotherid);
  const myentity = this.entities.find(x => x.id === data.anotherid)
  if (typeof myentity !== 'undefined') {
    //do something to update local data
  }
}
```

and the issue has gone away.

I'm coming to the conclusion that with the slow link, its possible for `doUpdate` to get called twice, the second time before the `readSomthingFromRemoteDatabase` has responded, and the second call has come in with different data.

What that implies is that the `const data` is within the scope of the called function for the entire scope of its execution, but that the parameter variable `e` is not.

However, I can find no documented information about whether my assumption is true. Can someone point me to where I can find out if my assumption is true?

UPDATE in response to some of the comments.

Firstly, `doUpdate` is an event listener which is called via `lit-element`. Elsewhere in this class is a Lit `render` function, a bit like this

```
render() {
 return html`
  ${this.entities.map(entity => html`
    <entity-editor .entity=${entity} @entity-changed=${this.doUpdate}></entity-editor>
  `)}
 `;
}
```

The event detail is an object constructed from parts, so not a reference elsewhere. Normally made something like this (inside the `entity-editor` custom element.

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('entity-changed', {
  bubbles: true,
  composed: true,
  detail: {
   anotherid: this.id,
   moreinfo: this.moreinfo
  )
}));
```

`readSomethingFromRemoteDatabase` does little more than translate the object passed into a `fetch` POST request to the server, where the object passed is `JSON.stringify`'ed into the `body` of the request.

Sorry that I can't point you at real code - but this is a massive PUA I personally have been building since 2016 advancing through `Polymer` and now `Lit` to replace a Microsoft Access Application. It's private work for a company so is in a private repository.

At this stage it's 100s of elements in a client, and 100s of components in a Node.js api-server (proxied by NGINX)

Comment: That would only make sense when `e` is a reference to an object that is changed outside of `doUpdate()` while `doUpdate()` "waits" for `readSomethingFromRemoteDatabase()`. But your question doesn't have an actual [mcve] so we don't know what `e` is and where/when/how `doUpdate()` is called.

Comment: it may depend on what `.detail` is

Comment: Is `doUpate()` an event listener?

Comment: Update your question to show how your function is called perhaps

Comment: Is your ```readSomethingFromRemoteDatabase()``` function returning a Promise or is it just another async function ?

Comment: Could you tell us what's in the mysterious errors? Have you logged and compared what `e.detail` contains per each version of your `doUpdate` method? Maybe the function is being called somewhere else and the response event is not what you're expecting?

Comment: `.find(e => e.id === e.detail.anotherid)` would imply that `this.entities` is an array of items that have an `id` and a `detail` property that has a `anotherid` property ... and none of that code has anything to do with the `e` that the `doUpdate(e)` function was called with ... so the two versions of code do completely different things ... javascript doesn't "know" which `e` you "meant" ...

Comment: @SARANSURYA - an async function, by definition, returns a Promise

Comment: what happens if the first code is `this.entities.find(x => x.id === e.detail.anotherid)` instead?

Comment: Another possibility (given the first code makes no sense anyway, for the reason I gave above) is that `e.detail` is clearly an object, and you are mutating that object outside of this function during the `await`

Comment: @JaromandaX yes it should have been that - I made this up as a simple example really quickly, I've updated it

Comment: You can try something like `Object.defineProperty(e, "detail", { set(val) { debugger; }});` to check what's modifying it.

Comment: in that case, it's probably my most recent suggestion - *Normally made something like this* - but probably different enough that `detail:` is some object you keep mutating - seeing as the code you posted where the custom event is clearly not valid, my guess is you're still not showing quite enough